# set a variable that counts the number of pallets in my storage anylogic

Tags: anylogic

as the title suggests, I would like to set an int variable that keeps track of the pallets I have in my storage

I tried to use the count() function but I get the error message that I can't use the count function for the storage type, how can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the functions

```
out.count()
```

or

```
in.count()
```

Nevertheless, you can just use your int variable and on exit and on enter you do `variable++` and `variable--` without using count